# Playframework 2.8 setSession works on Postman, but not on browser

Tags: scala, google-chrome, session, cookies, playframework

I've been working on an api project on Scala Playframework 2.8.
Everything seems to work fine on Postman, but when trying to connect it to my frontend project, `.withSession` doesn't create any cookie in the browser although it does create one in Postman.

I thought it had something to do with the `csrf` and `cors` definitions on the api's `application.conf` but I've edited it a lot and nothing works.

I'm getting no errors, just don't get the session to be set in the client, so i can't log-in anyone to the api :\

I'm sharing my `application.conf` code:

```
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Configuration

# Default database configuration using MySQL database engine
# Connect to playdb as playdbuser
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="blabla"
db.default.username="blalba"
db.default.password="blabla"

play.http.session.secure = false
play.http.session.cookieName = "PLAY_SESSION"
play.http.session.httpOnly = true

play.filters.disabled+=play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter
play.cache.bindCaches = ["db-cache"]

play.filters.hosts {
  allowed = ["."]
}

play.filters.enabled += "play.filters.cors.CORSFilter"
play.filters.cors {
  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS"]
  allowedHttpHeaders = ["Accept", "Content-Type"]

}

play.http.secret.key = "blablabla"
```

Anyone has an idea why the browser blocks me from creating the session from the Scala playframework 2.8 api?

Comment: Your config looks OK. Usually the browser tells you inside the console why / when it blocked some cookies. Look at the request data, does the response contain a `Set-Cookie` header?

Comment: Thanks for your response @cbley.

I'm using `.withSession(...)`, also tried `withCookies(..).bakeCookies()`. sadly nothing worked. on Postman it works as expected.

And there's no error from the browser side. the front is react.js and it's trying to reach to the scala backend. don't see any error in browser nor in sbt console...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. (I feel so stupid :/)
The problem wasn't with the backend, Play was working as expected.
The problem was with the frontend (react.js).

Once I added `credentials: 'include'` to the fetch call, it worked.

Started realising the problem is not in the backend thanks to @cbley's response, so thank you for that.